# Why am I getting an undefined error from this jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to ensure there is always an image with a personal bio. There could be two images or none available to use (coming in from Xpath Parser feed). If no image is found in the XML, I want to load a default placeholder. Console tells me this line "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined". I've tried many things to fix it but not having any luck. Any advise is appreciated.

```
if ($('.a_class').attr('src').indexOf('jpg') == -1 
    && $('.b_class').attr('src').indexOf('jpg') == -1) {

    $('.a_class').attr('src', '/folder/default_img.JPG');
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a snippet or a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? Or at least post your HTML here

Comment: It means that either `.a_class` or `.b_class` doesn't exist, or if they do, at least one of them doesn't have a src attribute.

Comment: Im with Jugana, can you run these two lines for us? `console.log($('.a_class').length);console.log($('.b_class').length);` what is the output? It would also be helpful to show your html

Comment: I just want to clarify if when you say "at least one of them doesn't have a source attribute" do you mean that one of them returned nothing at all? If so, that shouldn't be the case but I can check. thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off, running the same jQuery selector multiple times is expensive. In my experience, saving the selector makes the Javascript visibly more responsive:

```
var aClass = $('.a_class');
var bClass = $('.b_class');
```

According to jQuery's [attr(attributeName)](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName%20attr(attributeName)) documentation, it can return undefined if the attribute is not set, so you have a few things to check in your if condition. I'd also cache the result of `attr(attributeName)` in a variable:

```
var aClassSrc = aClass.attr('src');
var bClassSrc = aClass.attr('src');
```

This should finally work:

```
if ((typeof aClassSrc === "undefined" || aClassSrc.indexOf('jpg') == -1)
 && (typeof bClassSrc === "undefined" || bClassSrc.indexOf('jpg') == -1)) {
    aClass.attr('src', '/folder/default_img.JPG');
}
```

**Note** that we're assuming a_class and b_class exist somewhere in the part of the DOM you're searching, and they exist once. If they don't exist, the `attr(attributeName)` calls won't do anything without warning. Additionally, if there are multiple a_class or b_class elements, the `attr` call that sets the "src" tag will set it for every a_class element. Make sure you are OK with this.

Comment: The original logic seems fine to me, OP states *"There could be two images or none available to use (coming in from Xpath Parser feed). If no image is found in the XML, I want to load a default placeholder."*. I read this as "If neither has an image, I want to add 1 placeholder"

Comment: javaJake's answer looks very good, I haven't tried it yet but I will. Regarding the note and comments, reading the note made me realize there is a case where b_class will not exist, I assume that will be a problem. Most of the time both classes will be there, and only once each, but there is a rare case where b_class will not be there. I also now realize I should have mentioned that there is a preference when there is more than one image, if both images exist I want the one in a_class to load, and b_class to load only if there is no image in a_class, and the placeholder as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I used javaJake's answer as the foundation to write the rest of the necessary logic to hopefully make this work completely (see below). The code does not invoke any errors in the console. However, I have discovered that something (in the CMS) is hard-coded to override the javascript I'm adding to the page so I don't actually know if this works yet. Unless you see something glaringly obvious wrong with the code, I guess there is no point in responding just yet. I am looking into what is doing the override and will update the post when I do. I want to thank everyone for their help, comments, and suggestions thus far.

```
<script>
var aClass = $('.a_class');
var bClass = $('.b_class');
var cId = $('#c_Id');
var aClassSrc = aClass.attr('src');
var bClassSrc = bClass.attr('src');
// set default if nothing is returned in XML
if ((typeof aClassSrc === "undefined" || aClassSrc.indexOf('jpg') == -1) && (typeof bClassSrc === "undefined" || bClassSrc.indexOf('jpg') == -1)) {
cId.attr('src', '/folder/imagefield_default_images/bio_default_photo.JPG');
}
// if two images are returned, use aClass and hide bClass
else if ((typeof aClassSrc === "undefined" || aClassSrc.indexOf('jpg') >= 0) && (typeof bClassSrc === "undefined" || bClassSrc.indexOf('jpg') == 0))
$('.b_class').hide();
// if aClass is not preset, use bClass and hide aClass's broken image URL icon
else if ((typeof aClassSrc === "undefined" || aClassSrc.indexOf('jpg') >= -1) && (typeof bClassSrc === "undefined" || bClassSrc.indexOf('jpg') == 0))
$('.dm_image').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: It turns out the javascript is not being overridden but the code is not working. No errors but not working. I'm thinking it may be an issue with how the CMS nests several divs, each with their own class. I'm trying different methods of specifying the outermost div that encloses the rest but no luck yet.